# Clojure, update nested content in map

Tags: clojure

I am confused about the required syntax for updating a value in a map, where said value is a vector of maps.

Given a map:

```
   {:data-extracts [
                       {:name "some name"
                        :data "some data"
                        }]}
```

How can I update the value of :data, I know you can use `assoc` or `conj` to modify maps (well return new maps) but I'm unsure how this works when nested elements are present.

desired result:

```
   {:data-extracts [
                       {:name "some name"
                        :data "new data"
                        }]}
```

Is there a way to do something like the following?

```
(update :data-extracts :data "new data")
```

How is this achieveable?

I tried the following:

```
(assoc opts :data-extracts [:name "Secret Escapes"
                            :data "new data"]))
```

But that doesn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using nested structures, you'll want to use `*-in`-functions (in this case [`assoc-in`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc-in)) and specify one key for each nesting level. In case of vectors, it's just index, in case of maps it's obvious:

```
(assoc-in [:data-extracts 0 :data] "new data")
```

Comment: If i specify my map in the above like `(update-in my-map [:data-extracts 0 :data] "new data")` is tells me string cannot be cast to function. guessing because `"new data"` is not a string

Comment: @ChrisEdwards see the latest edit. I realized that shortly after posting, wiped the answer and edited it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I did come across assoc-in but couldnt figure out the syntax for my use case. Thanks.

Comment: The thing is, `update` acts on an existing value with a given function, when `assoc` just writes the given value in (...in terms of persistent data structures it's a bit different, but you get the idea).